# Auth:attempt fails on duplicate email

Tags: laravel-5.4

Im using Laravel then I've encountered a problem when logging in. I have a duplicate email in my database but I'm tagging them as different users by a column class_id. So how do I use class_id in logging in? When im using the email that has no duplicates it works.

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

**Specifying Additional Conditions**

If you wish, you may also add extra conditions to the authentication query in addition to the user's e-mail and password.

```
Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'class_id' => 'user's class id']);
```

Laravel expects email as unique field. You may use an additional field like username.
[Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#authenticating-users)

Hope it helps. If any error occurred let me know..